# .git folders appearing as .git file?

Tags: git, windows-7

As of this morning, any time I clone a repository the usual .git directories are appearing as .git files. I've got no file associations in the registry that I can see, and nobody at the office knows what's going on. I'm running Windows 7. What could be causing this?

EDIT: This appears to only happen to submodules.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be linked to submodules as:

- a git repo has only one .git directory of its own
- a submodule not yet loaded in that git repo will contain a 'git-file' as [introduced in 2008](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/2/4/719344)

From the [git repository layout documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitrepository-layout):

You may find these things in your git repository (`.git` directory for a repository associated with your working tree, or `'project'.git` directory for a public 'bare' repository.
**It is also possible to have a working tree where `.git` is a plain ascii file containing `gitdir: <path>\n`, i.e. the path to the real git repository**).

See the [Git Book on Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you! As it turns out, I had cloned the project months ago with an older version of git (probably pre-2008). Updated git a while back and has only cloned with the new version this morning producing this file.